# AutoIT Server menu to command prompts

Tags: batch-file, autoit, minecraft

I am trying to make a GUI menu that can start and stop a number of servers. In addition, it should be able to send commands to the servers with different parameters through check boxes and manual command additions such as "playername". What I need is to find a way to get the info menu working (It is waiting for the buttons I think), and find a way to send commands to the three command prompts that opens. I am still going to add two more servers and a bungee server, but if it works with three, it works with six.

```
Func Hub_func()
    Run(@ComSpec & " /C Java -Xmx1024M -jar spigot-1.6.2-R0.1.jar", "E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\Bungee Servers\Hub")
    Run(@ComSpec & " /C Java -Xmx1024M -jar spigot-1.6.2-R0.1.jar", "E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\Bungee Servers\Survival")
    Run(@ComSpec & " /C Java -Xmx1024M -jar spigot-1.6.2-R0.1.jar", "E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\Bungee Servers\Plotworld")
EndFunc   ;==>Hub_func
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <GuiToolbar.au3>
#include <StaticConstants.au3>
#include <ToolbarConstants.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
Opt("GUIResizeMode", $GUI_DOCKLEFT)
#region ### START Koda GUI section ### Form=c:\users\kristian\desktop\test.kxf
$Test = GUICreate("KnarCraft Client", 945, 1003, 957, 0)
GUISetFont(10, 400, 0, "MT Extra")
$Button1 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Exit", 848, 950, 75, 30)
GUICtrlSetFont(-1, 18, 400, 0, "MS Sans Serif")
GUICtrlSetResizing(-1, $GUI_DOCKAUTO + $GUI_DOCKRIGHT + $GUI_DOCKBOTTOM + $GUI_DOCKWIDTH + $GUI_DOCKHEIGHT)
GUICtrlSetTip(-1, "Exits the program")
$Button2 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Start Server", 24, 950, 139, 33)
GUICtrlSetFont(-1, 18, 400, 0, "MS Sans Serif")
GUICtrlSetResizing(-1, $GUI_DOCKLEFT + $GUI_DOCKBOTTOM + $GUI_DOCKWIDTH + $GUI_DOCKHEIGHT)
GUICtrlSetTip(-1, "Starts the KnarCraft server")
$ToolBar1 = _GUICtrlToolbar_Create($Test, 0)
$Checkbox1 = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox("Hide Console", 32, 928, 113, 17)
GUICtrlSetFont(-1, 12, 400, 0, "MS Sans Serif")
$Checkbox2 = GUICtrlCreateCheckbox("Old Version", 32, 904, 105, 17)
GUICtrlSetFont(-1, 12, 400, 0, "MS Sans Serif")
$Pic1 = GUICtrlCreatePic("D:\Bilder\Gameplay\b7223189a2371e69fabe26c661fae55d.jpeg", 0, 0, 937, 881)
$filemenu = GUICtrlCreateMenu("File")
$fileitem = GUICtrlCreateMenuItem("Open...", $filemenu)
$recentfilesmenu = GUICtrlCreateMenu("Recent Files", $filemenu)
$separator1 = GUICtrlCreateMenuItem("", $filemenu)
$exititem = GUICtrlCreateMenuItem("Exit", $filemenu)
$helpmenu = GUICtrlCreateMenu("?")
$aboutitem = GUICtrlCreateMenuItem("About", $helpmenu)
$tipsitem = GUICtrlCreateMenuItem("Tips", $helpmenu)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)
#endregion ### END Koda GUI section ###
While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
        Case $Button1
            MsgBox(64, "KnarCraft", "KnarCraft client will now close")
            Exit
        Case $Button2
            Hub_func()
    EndSwitch
WEnd
While 1
    $msg = GUIGetMsg()
    Select
        Case $msg = $fileitem
            $file = FileOpenDialog("Choose file...", @TempDir, "All (*.*)")
            If @error <> 1 Then GUICtrlCreateMenuItem($file, $recentfilesmenu)
        Case $msg = $aboutitem
            MsgBox(0, "About", "GUI Menu Test")
        Case $msg = $tipsitem
            MsgBox(0, "Tips", "You can do lots with this client.")
    EndSelect
WEnd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested your code but from the look of it your script is stuck in the first `while` loop. AutoIt scripts must have just one event loop. You should consider to put the conditions from the 2nd loop into the 1st loop like this:

```
While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
        Case $Button1
            MsgBox(64, "KnarCraft", "KnarCraft client will now close")
            Exit
        Case $Button2
            Hub_func()
        Case $fileitem
            $file = FileOpenDialog("Choose file...", @TempDir, "All (*.*)")
            If @error <> 1 Then GUICtrlCreateMenuItem($file, $recentfilesmenu)
        Case $aboutitem
            MsgBox(0, "About", "GUI Menu Test")
        Case $tipsitem
            MsgBox(0, "Tips", "You can do lots with this client.")
    EndSwitch
WEnd
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked :D BTW do you know how to send a command to the servers it opens? I don't know how to get it to write in the commanndprompts. I am pretty new to this stuff.

Comment: How exactly do you plan to communicate with the server? What kind of server is this? Your question is not quite clear. You should post another question for it and thereby put the question into other people's attention.